# why do we need to install JNA on cassandra ring?

Tags: cassandra, jna

I have read a lot of documentation on internet. Everyone says you should install the `JNA` on `cassandra` but no one gives the reason why? So, can anyone explain me how can installing `JNA` can improve the performance of `cassandra` cluster?

Answer (score 3):

Java Native Access (JNA) is a community-developed library that provides Java programs easy access to native shared libraries without using the Java Native Interface. JNA's design aims to provide native access in a natural way with a minimum of effort. (source: [Java Native Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access)

As per Datastax documentation Java Native Access (JNA) is required for production installations. Installing JNA can improve Cassandra memory usage. When installed and configured, Linux does not swap out the JVM, and thus avoids related performance issues.